# How to grant user full access to specific region but readonly access to all other regions

Tags: terraform, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I have a requirement to restrict access to all regions(except for s3 bucket item modifications) except for `eu-west-2`. the user can view all regions on the console but their access will be readonly for the most part, apart from being able to modify s3 bucket items. but for a specific region `eu-west-2` we would want to allow full access.

the following is what I have come up with so far but am not sure how denying all other access will affect my current statements.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "developer" {
  source_policy_documents = [data.aws_iam_policy.power_user.policy]

  statement {
    sid     = "DoNotAllowAnyOtherRolesOrUsers"
    actions = ["iam:*"]
    not_resources = [
      "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:role/*",
      "arn:aws:iam::${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}:user/*"
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid       = "DenyAssumingOtherRoles"
    effect    = "Deny"
    actions   = ["sts:AssumeRole*"]
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "DenyLogsModification"
    effect = "Deny"
    actions = [
      "logs:DeleteLogStream",
      "logs:DeleteLogGroup",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
    ]
    resources = ["*"]
  }

  statement {
    sid           = "DenySecretsRetrieval"
    effect        = "Deny"
    actions       = ["secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"]

    condition {
      test     = "Null"
      variable = "secretsmanager:ResourceTag/DeveloperAccess"

      values = [
        "true"
      ]
    }

    resources = ["*"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Deny always wins, so to me it seems that the deny for the role assumption will win over you allowing it in the statement before it. I would probably use the deny statement only, but with setting the `not_resources` in it.